# mongodb get count of orders in each zip code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Hi we are using rails with mongo and we have a collection called orders which contain a specific zip code for each customer. We want to retrieve a count of how many orders belong to each zip code and what time frame they appear in most.

The docs can have basic information such as :

```
{"zip" : 60010,
 "order_time" : <whatever the time for the order is>
}
```

Right now i have an aggregation using ruby:

```
coll_orders.aggregate([{"$group" => {"_id" => "$zip", "numOrders" => {"$sum" => 1}}}, {"$sort" => {"numOrders" => 1}}])
```

and it results with:

```
{"_id" : 60010,
"numOrders" : 55
}
```

My question is how do i add functionality in the aggregation so that i can get additional fields where it shows a breakdown of when the orders usually happen? Essentially a result document like :

```
{"_id" : 60010,
"numOrders" : 55,
"morning" : 25,
"afternoon" : 10,
"evening" : 20
}
```

edit: spelling/missed quotes

Comment: Did you look at the MongoDB Aggregation Framework?  I think that would be the way to go.  Also, if you need further help, please share more details (sample document, expected result, etc..) so others can better understand your requirement.

Comment: Sorry i added information and clarification as to what i specifically want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this would be calculate and store the minutes separately using a $project phase and use that to group by.  I have provided a sample query below that'll run in the shell for just calculating the orders placed in the morning.  You can extend this for the results you are expecting.

```
db.foo.aggregate( [ 
    { $project: {
        zip: 1,
        order_time: 1, 
        minutes: { $add: [
            { $multiply: [ { $hour: '$order_time' }, 60 ] }, 
            { $minute: '$order_time' } 
        ] } 
    } },
    { $group: {
         _id:"$zip", 
         numOrders:{$sum:1}
         morning:{$sum:{$cond:[{$lt:["$minutes",12*60]}, 1, 0]}}}}
] );
```

Comment: It does work! question though on the snippet: 

    morning:{$sum:{$cond:[{$lt:["$minutes",12*60]}, 1, 0]}}}}

What is the , 1, 0 for?

Comment: Like how we use $sum:1 for "numOrders", we need to use $sum:1 or $sum:0 for "morning" based on when the order was placed.  $cond is the operation to use achieve that behavior. Checkout the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)  From the documentation: `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }`.  Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following mongoid queries to fetch the data you need:

Count in each zip code:
`Order.where(:zip => zip).count`

And for count in a given time slot (you will need to create separate queries for each time slot - morning, afternoon, etc.):

`Order.where(:zip => zip, :order_time => {'$gt' => start_time, '$lt' => end_time}).count`

You can either keep inserting each unique zipcode in a separate collection to get a list of all zip codes, or if you don't run this task often (and your collection is small), you can get a list of all the unique zip codes in your collection using:

`zips = Order.all.map{|o| o.zip}.compact.uniq`

and iterate over this array and do the above queries.